# Ionic 2 RC0 Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings

Recently Ionic released the RC0 of Ionic Framework and I am exciting. But I use moment-timezone and it generated an error.

I installed moment and moment-timezone like so:

```
npm install --save moment moment-timezone

typings install --save --global dt~moment dt~moment-timezone
```

Then I import moment and tz like so:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

When I run `ionic build` I got error:

```
Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'.
```

My `ionic info` result is:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
ios-sim version: 5.0.8
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.11.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

> npm install @types/moment-timezone --save

Answer (score 1):

Since rc0 ionic stopped using typings and switched to @types.
So delete typings folder and typings.json

Install moment typings like so

```
npm install @types/moment --save
```

Comment: Should I maintain the normal `moment` and `moment-timezone`? Or use @types together?

Comment: @types are typescript definition types not the actual library so I am missing the question